# Iterar sobre JSON Angular

Tags: angular, ionic, typescript

Necesito almacenar en **localStorage** un `array de Objetos`

Cuando un usuario selecciona un **contacto** en la lista de contactos...

Obtengo los que habia anteriormente y le agrego el nuevo, sobreescribo el item de localStorage por uno nuevo.

```
localContacts = [];

  selectContact(contact) {
    this.localContacts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('contacts'));
    this.localContacts.push(contact);

    localStorage.setItem('contacts', JSON.stringify(this.localContacts));
    this.closeModal();
  }
```

En otra pagina distinta donde quiero recoger dichos contactos que usuario ha seleccionado... Uno por cada vez que abre el modal, por eso al final del método cierro el modal...

Otro `localContacts` vacio distinto, estamos en otra pagina...

```
localContacts = [];

this.localContacts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('contacts'));
```

Bien... resultaria bastante facil decir en el HTML...

```
<h3 *ngIf="localContacts.length == 0">No Contacts</h3>

    <ion-item *ngFor="let contact of localContacts">

    <h2>{{contact}}, {{contact.displayName}},{{localContacts[contact].displayName}}</h2>

</ion-item>
```

Todo lo que veis en el `<h2>` son pruebas, solo quiero acceder a las propiedades del objeto `contact`, principalmente a `displayName`.

El caso es que se que hay objetos en el interior... pues `localContacts.length == 0` es `false`. Ademas se imprime un `<ion-item>` por cada contacto que selecciono, pero en el interior del `<ion-item>` no puedo ver nada, `contact.PROPIEDAD`... es `undefined`

He intentando hacer una `Pipe` debido a que no se si angular puede iterar sobre arrays de objetos y tampoco funciona, he conseguido incluso imprimir el INDICE del objeto... `0,1,2,3` pero no sus propiedades...

El problema creo que esta al transformar a JSON y demás, pero debe ser un string para almacenar en localStorage por eso una vez tengo this.localContacts relleno le hago un `JSON.stringify()` para transformarlo y despues un `JSON.parse()`

Contenido de {{contact | json}}

```
{"_objectInstance":
   {"id":"88", 
   "rawId": null, 
   "displayName":"nombre", 
   "name":{
      "familyName":"x",
      "givenName":"nombre",
      "formatted":"nombre"},
   "nickname":null,
   "phoneNumbers":[{
      "id":"786", 
      "pref": false, 
      "value":"1111111111"},
      "type": "mobile"}],
    "emails": null,
    "addresses": null,
    "ims": null,
    "organizations": null,
    "birhday": null,
    "note": null,
    "photos":null,
    "categories": null,
    "urls": null},
    "rawId": "88"}
}
```

Los datos son inventados por motivos obvios...

¿Deberia por lo tanto esto de funcionar? No lo hace...

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let contact of localContacts">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let c of contact._objectInstance">

      <h2>c.displayName</h2>

    </ion-item>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Debe haber algo más que no estás viendo: Ese código debería funcionar, Angular itera sobre cualquier elemento iterable. Prueba a imprimir `{{ contact | json }}`, a ver qué te muestra

Comment: Te lo dejo arriba. Gracias

Comment: Pues ahí lo tienes: todo el objeto contact está dentro de `_objectInstance`. Ahora tienes que averiguar por qué y solucionarlo